# Helm values.yaml variables from kubernetes secret

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, terraform, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to use kubernetes secret in different helm charts and is any universal way to do it? For example I have grafana and admin password in helm values.yaml, and I want to keep it in k8s secret and load it into values.yaml . Is it possible? Grafana have option like admin.existingSecret but I also want to do it with charts where they don't have that options. Is it possible to do it with

```
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          name: mysecret
          key: WSO2_CLOUD_ORG_KEY
```

or with

```
envFromSecrets: ""
```

I tried to use it in values.yaml in elasticsearch exportet but it didn't work and I'm looking for any universal way to do it. I tried:

```
envFromSecrets: "secret"
es:
  uri: ${secret}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to keep it in k8s secret and load it into values.yaml

No it's not possible however you can create a template in the **chart** so if the secret is missing it will create the one with value

Not sure which chart you are using but can checkout the

https://github.com/grafana/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/grafana/values.yaml#L342

**values.yaml**

```
# Administrator credentials when not using an existing secret (see below)
adminUser: admin
# adminPassword: strongpassword
```

if you want to use the existing secret you can mention it in this section along with the **user** key and **password** key ref.

```
# Use an existing secret for the admin user.
admin:
  ## Name of the secret. Can be templated.
  existingSecret: ""
  userKey: admin-user
  passwordKey: admin-password
```

Comment: In grafana it works, bu what when I have chart which don't support it? For example I try to do it with elasticsearch and other charts like postgres operator, kafka, prometheus and I'm trying to find any universal way to do it but looks like every chart have different options

Comment: oh okay, in that case you edit the existing helm chart and it's template as per requirement it's straight forward to update those.